# Missing browsers in debugging dropdown menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webforms

When debugging websites in Visual Studio 2012 your debug dropdown should look like this:

[image]

<sub>via [hanselman.com](http://hanselman.com)</sub>

Mine has started to look like this:

[image]

...and breakpoints are not being hit.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I tried doing a repair to no avail!

This is very bizzare as two days ago it was working perfectly.

**Another update**

This only appears to happen on one project... something with that must have become corrupt some how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How irritating:

I closed VS, deleted `solutionName.sln.DotSettings.user` and `solutionName.v11.suo`, repopened and now it works perfectly.

Hopefully this will save someone a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Can u choose "Browse With..." option...

Comment: I can, but that does not initiate debugging.

Comment: Please do not post requests for clarification as answers on a post. Use the comments below the question instead!